# What to do when Mushaf is dropped or comes in contact with someones feet?

Tags: source-identification, mushaf, respect

From what I have observed from childhood, when a Mushaf of the Holy Qur'an accidentally comes in contact with someone's feet or when it falls down, people usually pick the Qur'an/Mushaf up,  touch it by their eyes and sometimes forehead, then kiss it and maybe ask for forgiveness in an audible voice and keep it in its place.

When I asked this to scholars, scholars of different schools had different opinions. Some said:

- Give sadaqah
- Offer  1 raka'ah salaah (at the same place if you can) and ask for forgiveness.
- kissing it was okay but some were against it

None of them provided any reference to this ruling/action.

What should one do if the Mushaf of the Holy Quran is accidentally dropped or comes in contact with someone's feet?

*A strongly referenced answers would be much appreciated.*

Comment: I think the kissing is a reflex move out of respect, similar to what people would do if they dropped a baby. I don't know if there's any official support for this, but it's the intuitive thing to do.

Answer (score 3):

According to [Fiqh](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ja%27fari_jurisprudence) of [Shia Islam](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shia_Islam) if it is intentional it is a great sin and even who commit this can be Murtadd (apostate) and should repent and cover it with good deeds. But if it is accidentally it has no sin and should quickly pick it and respect it. and anyway Quran should be protected and respected.

---

**References:**

[Online answering](http://makarem.ir/websites/english/?p=oas) of [Official website of Grand Ayatollah Makarem Shirazi](http://www.makarem.ir/)

Answer (score 2):

Kissing the Mushaf if it falls by the Sheikh Saalih al-Fouzaan -may Allah preserve him- [Reference below]

> Question: May Allah give you good possessor of excellence, the
>   Questioner asks: Some people when they drop the Mushaf they kiss it
>   (after picking it up), so what is the ruling concerning that with
>   mentioning the proof?
>
> Answer: There is no proof for that, kissing the Mushaf has no proof
>   for it. So if he/she drops the Mushaf then let him grab it and pick it
>   up and this is sufficient and all praise is due to Allah without (him)
>   kissing it.

Reference:http://www.salafitalk.net/st/viewmessages.cfm?Forum=6&Topic=10664